# How to cancel the downloading file using webclient?

Tags: c#, download, webclient

Here's my code to download the file.

```
WebClient client=new WebClient()
    public void DownloadFile()
    {
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressChanged);

                client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, fileName);

    }
```

Here's my code to cancel the downloading file.

```
public void CancelDownloadingFile()
{
      client.CancelAsync();
      client.Dispose();
}
```

But when i call the CancelDownloadingFile() method it does nothing. The File keeps downloading in the background. Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this using [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
CancellationTokenSource cts; // write this on top of your class

public void CancelDownloadingFile()
{
      if (cts != null)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj155759.aspx

possible duplicate : [How to cancel an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729346/how-to-cancel-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't actually answer OP's question, which is how to cancel a WebRequest.DownloadFileAsync call.