# How to catch TargetInvocationException raised from .Net BackgroundWorker in Matlab?

Tags: .net, matlab, exception, matlab-guide, targetinvocationexception

I am writing a small application in Matlab using GUIDE.
This application calls on a .Net library.
The library connects to a serial device.
Using a `BackgroundWorker`, the library polls the port for new data, and raises an `IncomingData` event whenever a new packet is received. (I know this because I used a decompiler to view the guts of the library.)

The problem is that the SDK I'm using didn't [implement the `RunWorkerCompleted` method properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2636352/3198973). It does not check to see if an exception occurred via the `e.Errors` property before accessing the `e.Result` property. This causes a [TargetInvocationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) to be thrown. This exception is going unhandled and causes Matlab to crash with the following event in the Windows event log. The inner exception is not serialized to the event log, so I don't know what's actually causing the failure.

> ```
> Application: MATLAB.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
> Stack:
>    at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>    at System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
>    at TargetInvocationIssueMVCE.BlackBox._backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
>    at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
>    at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(System.Object)
>    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,  System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>    at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
> ```

I was able to replicate the behavior of the library that I'm using with the following C# class library. You can think of this `BlackBox` example below as the library that I cannot change.

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TargetInvocationIssueMVCE
{
    public class BlackBox
    {
        private BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker;

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> IncomingData;

        public void Connect()
        {
            _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker()
            {
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };

            _backgroundWorker.DoWork += _backgroundWorker_DoWork;
            _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += _backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void _backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // BlackBox should check e.Errors first, but doesn't, so throws a TargetInvocationException that I can't seem to catch, so it crashes Matlab.
            Console.Write(e.Result == null ? "Failure" : "Success");
        }

        private void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("I could be any exception.");

            // the real worker is supposed to raise IncomingData here.
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling this library in a Matlab GUIDE GUI like this.

```matlab
% --- Executes just before Figure1 is made visible.
function Figure1_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to Figure1 (see VARARGIN)

% load the library

NET.addAssembly('C:\path\to\TargetInvocationIssueMVCE.dll');
blackbox = TargetInvocationIssueMVCE.BlackBox();
handles.blackbox = blackbox;

addlistener(blackbox, 'IncomingData', @OnIncomingData);

% Choose default command line output for Figure1
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% ... some other irrelevant callbacks

% --- button click callback starts .Net BackgroundWorker process
function btnConnect_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
try
    handles.blackbox.Connect();
    set(hObject, 'String', 'Disconnect');

catch ex
    warning(ex.message);
    set(hObject, 'Value', 1);
end

% --- Callback to process incoming data packets
function OnIncomingData(source, arg)
    % It doesn't matter what I put here, the exception is raised before
    % I ever get a packet event and Matlab crashes.

    msgbox('Received Packet');
```

---

In .Net, if I really had to, I could set up a catch in my `static void Main()` method so that I could inspect the inner exception.

```cs
try
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
catch (TargetInvocationException exception)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exception.InnerException.ToString());
}
```

I tried the same in Matlab by creating a Script to run the Figure, but it still did not catch the issue. It seems to somehow bypass the catch below. Matlab still crashes with the same event log that I get if I just double click `Figure1` to run it.

```matlab
try
    Figure1
catch ex
    warning(ex.message)
end
```

So, I really don't know where to go from here.
I *know* this is an XY problem. I don't *really* need to be able to catch this exception, but I ***do*** need to be able to inspect the inner exception and I don't what else I can do to get a look at it.

---

I just found this [interesting tidbit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/233507-catching-error-in-subfunction-with-global-try-catch#answer_189115).

> Callbacks of all kinds are executed in the context of the base
>   workspace, not in the context of the routine that set the Callback
>   function. You can only "catch" the exceptions of statements you call
>   directly, not of functions automatically executed on your behalf
>   through a callback.

If this is true, it would explain why I can't catch the exception when creating the figure from a script. Am I screwed? Does this mean I *can't* catch this exception?