# Where is the exception caught? (Try/Catch)

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

When using the back ground worker class to call a method within a try catch statement, and a try catch statement is in the method, which one catches the exception?

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Do();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Result + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And:

```
private void Do ()
{
   try
   {
       //Do something, open a file etc.
       FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Result + ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Called with: `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();`

Is there a way to make sure the exception is handled within the method? so the backgroundworker doesn't break?

Comment: Which exception? *"so the backgroundworker doesn't break"* - indicates you have some problem with code above, which problems?

Comment: If an exception is unhandled in your `DoWork` function, then it will be passed as part of the arguments to your `RunWorkerCompleted` function. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258662/unhandled-exceptions-in-backgroundworker).

Comment: Put in a breakpoint, or add something to the log to see which one is writing it out.  Either would have taken you only a few seconds to check.

Comment: No Servy, no. when the backgroundworker class breaks in VS2015, it doesn't show you where it breaks. Hence my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner one since this catch is "closer" to the "error"

this one :

```
private void Do ()
{
   try
   {
       //Do something, open a file etc.
       FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Result + ex.Message);
   }
}
```